# Sharepoint 2010 - updating large list , processes very slowly and times out

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a situation where I have to update a source records list status column to either open or closed, based on if the records have an open or closed project - the project list can have a number of projects linked to the source record by the ID of the source record and client ID in the projects, the code is to retrieve the clients projects and then check if there is an end date, if there isn't - its open - if there is - its closed. These sharepoint lists are large

I have written code which basically allows me to specify a start ID and then it will process so many records before stopping when I click a run button - I put this in place as the process was painfully slow and was even timing out, but I don't see why its so slow and well .. unstable - if I try process any more than 150 records - it times out, the server itself is an eight core system with 24gb ram so I don't think its the server, Its probably my code.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
        string SPsiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
        Label1.Text = "Running";
        int start;
        start = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        start = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        int end = start + 150;
        int count = 0;

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPsiteUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb("/Client"))
            {
                // get lists
                SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Source Records"];
                SPList pList = oWeb.Lists["Project"];

                // query Source Records 
                string sQuery = @"<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + start + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'> "+ end +"</Value></Leq></And></Where>";
                string sViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='ID' />";
                string sViewAttrs = @"Scope=""Recursive""";
                uint iRowLimit = 0;

                var oQuery = new SPQuery();
                oQuery.Query = sQuery;
                oQuery.ViewFields = sViewFields;
                oQuery.ViewAttributes = sViewAttrs;
                oQuery.RowLimit = iRowLimit;

                SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

                // for each item

                foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
                {
                    // get the client id 

                    int id = oListItem.ID;

                        count = count + 1; 
                        //Label1.Text = "Checking record" + id;
                        bool isopen = false;
                        // for each client id access the projects list
                        // query the closed date
                        string Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Client_x003a_ID"" /><Value Type=""Text"">" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                        string pViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name=""End_x0020_Date"" />";
                        string pViewAttrs = @"Scope=""Recursive""";
                        uint pRowLimit = 0;
                        var pQuery = new SPQuery();
                        pQuery.Query = Query;
                        pQuery.ViewFields = pViewFields;
                        pQuery.ViewAttributes = pViewAttrs;
                        pQuery.RowLimit = pRowLimit;
                        SPListItemCollection ListItems = pList.GetItems(pQuery);

                        foreach (SPListItem ListItem in ListItems)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DateTime enddate = (DateTime)ListItem["End_x0020_Date"];
                                if (enddate != null)
                                {
                                    isopen = false;
                                }
                                // else if the date is null set the open to true
                                else
                                {
                                    isopen = true;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                string enddate = null;
                                if (enddate == null)
                                {
                                    // if the end date is present set project closed to true
                                    isopen = true;
                                }
                            }

                        // if project is open
                        if (isopen)
                        {
                            oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            SPListItem itemupdate = oWeb.Lists["Source Records"].Items.GetItemById(id);
                            itemupdate["Status"] = "Open";
                            itemupdate.Update();
                            oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            // set records on source record to open
                        }
                        //else // project is closed
                        //{
                        //    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        //    SPListItem itemupdate = oWeb.Lists["Source Records"].Items.GetItemById(id);
                        //    itemupdate["Status"] = "Closed";
                        //    itemupdate.Update();
                        //    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        //    // set the record to closed 
                        //}
                    }
                }
                Label1.Text = "Finished Number of records checked: " + count + " of " + collListItems.Count;
            }
        }
    }'
```

Comment: The code was the encoded file pulled from the wsp - have edited to include the whole code including commented out code

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
SPListItem itemupdate = oWeb.Lists["Source Records"].Items.GetItemById(id);
```

try this:

```
SPListItem itemupdate = oWeb.Lists["Source Records"].GetItemById(id);
```

Comment: His problem is that he is performing complex and expensive queries in a loop, and that's where his major costs lie.  This change isn't going to make much of a difference at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I strongly disagree here. SPList.Items is a very expensive operation. Essentially it will retrieve all items from the list. It's happening in a loop. So. If there are 1000-2000 items in "Source Records" list it's going to take a lot of time consideting "foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)". Overall there are several serious problems with this code, not just one. For instance, SPWeb.Lists[""] is also pretty expensive operation that you should move out from the loop etc

Comment: But it's only happening conditionally.  It's *a* problem, but it doesn't change the fact that the core design of this algorithm is flawed.  He shouldn't be fetching items by ID inside of a double nested loop *at all*, in addition to the fact that he shouldn't even *have* a double nested loop in which each loop represents a DB query.  So while this does fix something, it still leaves a broken solution when you're done.

Answer (score -2):

You need to update your code for the nested loop. Instead of this:

```
foreach (SPListItem item1 in sPList.GetItems(sPQuery1))
```

try to use this:

```
SPListItemCollection items1 = sPList.GetItems(sPQuery1);
foreach (SPListItem item1 in items1)
```

Please refer to this [blog post](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/) for details.

UPDATE: You have to try and get rid of nested loop. I think you can accomplish that by adding a reference at the source list to the list of project, and refer to the `End Date` column there.

Comment: The change that you're suggesting wouldn't change a thing.  The `foreach` loop only evaluates the `IEnumerable` object once, not on every iteration of the loop.  It's an entirely different case than the blog post you linked to.